# Porting Arrays.copyOfRange from Java 6 to Java 5

Tags: java, arrays, java-6, java-5

I have some source code that I need to make runnable under Java 5. Unfortunetly that code uses [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) function which was only introduced in Java 6. What would be the most effective way to implement same utility using only Java 5 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [OpenJDK 6 page](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/) - it's open source Java. You can download and read the source code yourself, find out how it's implemented, and add the functionality to the app manually.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I found the implementation.

Comment: Nice! OpenJDK has been around for a while, and is great for reading up on any concept you want to understand better.

Answer (score 4):

Here goes the code from OpenJDK for those who are intrested:

```
public static byte[] copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to) {
    int newLength = to - from;
    if (newLength < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
    byte[] copy = new byte[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to use `System.arraycopy`. It's what's done by the Arrays class, BTW.