# can't use Arrays.copyOfRange

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't seem to be able to access Arrays.copyOfRange in my Android project in Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1 On Ubuntu 11.10.

My JRE is java-6-openjdk which I thought included Arrays.copyOfRange

For example, if I have this code:

```
int[] debug = new int[5];
int[] x = Arrays.copyOfRange(debug,0,4);
```

Eclipse tells me

> The method `copyOfRange(int[], int, int)` is undefined for the type `Arrays`

I don't understand because the Android reference [Arrays](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html) includes this method for Arrays.

Any ideas?

Comment: yikes, a -1.  If you're the -1 voter, kindly explain. Thanks.

Comment: @slayton ok, I've added some code.  Please reconsider the -1 votes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `Arrays.copyOfRange()` wasn't introduced until API level `9`. Make sure you are using that as the minimum SDK.

Also, you are indexing incorrectly. In java if you have an array of size `5` the indices range from `0->4`

Change your code to this:

```
int[] debug = new int[5];
int[] x = Arrays.copyOfRange(debug,0,4); // use 4 instead of 5
```

Comment: @slaton :  thanks, I've changed the code in my example, but the problem is that the method isn't even recognized, no matter what value I use.

Comment: the `copyOfRange` methods were not introduced into the android sdk until API level 9.  If you want to use those methods you'll have to configure your API level accordingly.   Also you can simply write your own array copy method.

Comment: thanks, yes now I see.  I think this was not an obvious solution, and that this question no longer warrants down votes, so please consider an up vote.

Comment: I forgot to mention:  I don't know how this works, but should you update the text of your answer with the point you made in your comment about the API level so I can accept it?  Thanks.

Comment: @aez ok, i added it to the answer

Comment: Yes, Arrays.copyOfRange do not exist in Android API levels < 9. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10054

Comment: But you can implement the function copyOfRange, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7970678/1173350

Comment: Nice. Android using Java 1.6, where the copyOfRange method was added, has had the Arrays class since SDK 1, but you need SDK 9 anyways.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use an API older than 9, System.arraycopy and Math.min was added in API level 1, so you can copy the copyOf function and use it in your code.

```
public static byte[] copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength) {
    byte[] copy = new byte[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Arrays.copyOfRange has been introduced to the Arrays class with Java 6. Android is based on Java 5. You cannot use Java 6 methods or classes with Android.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but I don't understand why it's included in the Android  reference webpage [Android Arrays](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: If its in the android docs then its supported by the Dalvik VM, however it may not be present in all API levels